# Is the value returned by PagerAdapter getCount() expected to remain static?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter, android-viewpager2

Or is it perfectly fine to increase the value returned as the user scrolls through the views?

In all examples for a PagerAdapter the value returned is the size of some Collection, thus a static value. The API also doesn't specify wether the value returned by `getCount()` is expected to remain static.

The question also applies for the `getItemCount()` method of `RecyclerView.Adapter` for `ViewPager2`.